# Excel userform occasionally will not enter data into the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

The userform I created in Excel VBA to enter data into a database works, however occasionally my users report that data they've entered using the form does not populate on the spreadsheet.  I'm new to coding in Excel VBA and programming in general so I'm not sure the best way to troubleshoot a problem like this.

Please note this problem is intermittent, so I don't know if it's something the user is doing or not doing.

I originally thought the data might be populating at the bottom of the spreadsheet because of an error with the 'find first empty row in database section, however I did not find any data there.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("QA Data")

'find first empty row in database
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for lookup code
If Trim(Me.txtLookup_Code.Value) = "" Then
    Me.txtLookup_Code.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please enter a Lookup Code"
    Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'   with your password
'   if worksheet is protected
With ws
'   .Unprotect Password:="password"
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtLookup_Code.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cboCM_Name.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtCM_Errors.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cboSP_Site.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cboChecklist_Type.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.txtActivity_Description.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.cboProcessor_Name.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.txtCritical_Errors.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.txtNon_Critical_Errors.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Date
    .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Application.UserName
'   .Protect Password:="password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.txtLookup_Code.Value = ""
Me.cboCM_Name.Value = ""
Me.txtCM_Errors.Value = ""
Me.cboSP_Site.Value = ""
Me.cboChecklist_Type.Value = ""
Me.txtActivity_Description.Value = ""
Me.cboProcessor_Name.Value = ""
Me.txtCritical_Errors.Value = ""
Me.txtNon_Critical_Errors.Value = ""
Me.txtLookup_Code.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cName As Range
Dim cSite As Range
Dim cCheck As Range
Dim cProcessor As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")

For Each cName In ws.Range("CMName")
  With Me.cboCM_Name
    .AddItem cName.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cName.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End With
Next cName

For Each cSite In ws.Range("SPSite")
    With Me.cboSP_Site
        .AddItem cSite.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cSite.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next cSite

For Each cCheck In ws.Range("ChecklistType")
    With Me.cboChecklist_Type
        .AddItem cCheck.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cCheck.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next cCheck

For Each cProcessor In ws.Range("ProcessorName")
    With Me.cboProcessor_Name
        .AddItem cProcessor.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cProcessor.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next cProcessor

Me.txtLookup_Code.SetFocus

End Sub
```

I expect the spreadsheet to populate with the data that was entered when the "Add" button is pressed, however occasionally it will not work.

Comment: Not seeing anything obvious. One issue it could be is not referring to the correct workbook. If there is another workbook open with a sheet called `QA Data` it might cause an issue. Try updating this `Set ws = Worksheets("QA Data")` to `Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("QA Data")`. Also, make sure the data actually isn't there. It might be that the data is being appended farther down than expected.

Comment: I would agree with @RyanWildry. Alternatively, is it possibe users are renaming the worksheet? Maybe direct it to the sheetID name rather than the Name?

Comment: Your Find is missing the `After` argument (should be A1) so it's possible it's not finding the *last* row.  That could lead to overwriting existing data: I always check the row is really empty before writing anything.

Comment: I would try the `.end(xlup)` method of defining your rows.  Is it possible multiple users can be updating?

Comment: Thank you all!  Ryan - I looked all the way to the end and the data was not there.  PGCodeRider - I don't think they are but I will modify it like you said just to be sure.  Nathan - Each user has their own spreadsheet, so it's not shared.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
```

will find a value that is not only at the last row, but also the last column in that row.

You can imagine it searching from `ws.Range($XFD$1048576)` to `ws.Range("$A$1")` searching right to left, then moving up a row. So, if by chance, there existed a value at `ws.Range("$AA$57)` your output would end up on the 58th row.

A more consistent approach to finding the last row used for your purpose--since you're goal is to sequentially enter data into columns 1-13--would be to let `lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row + 1`.
With this method, you're only searching column A for the last populated row and then stepping down one to the next empty row.
To further eliminate outlier errors, it may be in your best interest to `set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QA Data")`.

As far as suggestions for debugging an issue like this, you could create an additional worksheet, we'll call it "Error" for this example, and at the end of your code for CommandButton1_Click() add

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Error")
    .Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = "Data Entry Point @ Row " & lRow
End With
```

just to see where your data is ouputting.

Comment: Thank you Tate!  I will use the xlup, that seems more efficient and less error-prone.  Also the debug screen will definitely come in handy if this happens again.